# Install M2 Release Plugin 0.9.1 on Hudson 2.2.1?

Tags: maven-2, hudson, hudson-plugins

Has anyone successfully installed the latest M2 Release Plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Release+Plugin or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) on Hudson (NOT Jenkins) 2.2.1?

I just upgraded Hudson from 2.1.2 to 2.2.1 (deployed in Glassfish 3.1) and when I try to upgrade the plugin from 0.8.1, I get a 500 server error with this stack trace:

```
[#|2012-08-24T15:12:37.250-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=72;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WebModule[/hudson]Error while serving http://myserver:8080/hudson/pluginManager/install
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:103)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$3.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:167)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:489)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:160)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.getNeededDependencies(UpdateSite.java:580)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.deploy(UpdateSite.java:622)
        at hudson.PluginManager.doInstall(PluginManager.java:539)
        ... 81 more
|#]

[#|2012-08-24T15:12:37.252-0600|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=72;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[Stapler]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Stapler threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.getNeededDependencies(UpdateSite.java:580)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.deploy(UpdateSite.java:622)
        at hudson.PluginManager.doInstall(PluginManager.java:539)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:103)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$3.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:167)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:489)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:160)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
        at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled the 0.8.1 version of the plugin and installed the 0.9.1 version and also the Jenkins javadoc 1.0 plugin and both seem to have installed successfully (not sure if there will be any weirdness caused by the javadoc plugin).

However, when I view my job's configure page, it looks very different from the M2 Release plugin page screenshots.  I don't know how much that is a Hudson/Jenkins difference or a plugin issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more playing around, I've discovered that the `Build Environment` section and the `Perform Maven Release` link that are shown in the plugin page's screenshots, are available when one chooses to `Build a maven2/3 project`.  It is not available in the free-style job configuration.

Our installation of Hudson has had the`Hudson :: Maven (legacy) :: Plugin` disabled and so that type of job is not available.  This was done a recommendation to use the free-style job type for Maven builds since Maven3 is now bundled with Hudson.

You don't need the plugin to do a Maven release in Hudson, you can simply invoke the goals `release:prepare` and `release:perform` in the `Invoke Maven 3` build step.  You can't customize the version and SCM comment prefixes, but it works!